# How can I create a Rails search bar facility without using additional gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am building a small classifieds application for our community where folks can list products for sale using a form with *params* description and image only.

Both params are in the schema.rb

THE PROBLEM:

I have embedded the search bar on my index.html.erb and also created a show.html.erb which is blank. Currently the search bar does *nothing* except look pretty,

I am struggling to understand how to get the search wired up to interrogate the description param and deliver the results onto my show.html.erb.

NB: I would like the show.html.erb page and its search results to mirror my index page cosmetically and achieve this task without having to install any further gems.

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def index
@pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page =>   params[:page], :per_page => 15)
end


def show
end


def new
@pin = current_user.pins.build
end


def edit
end


def create
@pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
if @pin.save
  redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
else
  render :new
end
end


def update
if @pin.update(pin_params)
redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
else
render :edit
end
end


def destroy
@pin.destroy
redirect_to pins_url
end


private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_pin
  @pin = Pin.find_by(id: params[:id])
end

def correct_user
  @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the   white list through.
def pin_params
  params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your index method to either have a search query or not.

```
def index
  if params[:query]
    @results = Advert.where('lower(description) LIKE ?', '%#{params[:query].downcase}%')
  else
    @results = Advert.all
  end
end
```

You can also create filters using javascript or install either `searchkick` gem or if you need something REALLY simple install `rails4-autocomplete`

Comment: and how do i get the search results rendered onto my view/pins/show.html.erb

Comment: The `show` should not be for search results. It should be for a specific advertisement alone. If you want the show to be the search results add the part with the query to the show method.

Comment: so are you saying, do not add this to the index.if params[:query]
    results = Advert.where('lower(description) LIKE ?', '%#{params[:query].downcase}%')
  else
    results = Advert.all
  end
end

Comment: my apologies, i have a search.html.erb file blank ( I am not wanting this wired to show)

Comment: I say it should be added to index. I said show is for something like `Advert.find(1)` or `Advert.where('lower(description) LIKE ?', '%#{params[:query].downcase}%').first` for example. For showing a single item but index is for listing that is why search should be in the index method.

Comment: You do not need a `search.html.erb` use the `index.html.erb` for displaying search results.

Comment: my controller is not called advert. it is pin. I assume I should swap this in your syntax

Comment: You mean your model name. And yes.

Comment: No man. Add it to the controller. I am saying your model name is Pin

Comment: does not work. nothing changes and no search results are rendered

Comment: Elaborate more in your question. Maybe add your whole controller and search form.